# Server in Python: write or add parameters on URL possible without redirect

Tags: python-2.7, cherrypy

I need the command for working the Url using CherryPy and Python version 2.7.3

I want to change the url.

Old Url is

```
localhost:8080
```

and automatically adding `foo=1&foo=2` (**variable s**) in the Url

```
localhost:8080?=foo=1&foo=2


import cherrypy
import urllib

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        jsondict = [('foo', '1'), ('foo', '2')]
        s = urllib.urlencode(jsondict)
        print s
        #foo=1&foo=2

        return "Hello"


cherrypy.config.update({
    'global': {
        'server.socketPort': 8080
    }
})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

There is a solution?

Using the suggestion's Andrew with
 `raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080?" + params).`

This is working but this is for redirect.

This I am not interested but write on new url using the redirect.

I don't want the redirect but I working always on this url, adding the Query String without redirect.

It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just a simple redirect?

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        urlVar = 1
        urlVar2 = 2
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080?foo=" + str(urlVar) + "&fooo=" + str(urlVar2))

cherrypy.config.update({
    'global': {
        'server.socketPort': 8080
    }
})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: Error...
I compiled your program...
500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it

Comment: from fulfilling the request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "serv.py", line 34, in index
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080?foo=" + urlVar + "&fooo=" + urlVar2)

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: I vote you for the suggestion and not for the better answer.<
I changed your project (look on the question) and function.
But I am interest work on Url without the Redirect..

Comment: I've updated my answer with the fix for that.  I've added str(urlVar).

Comment: I see you updated your question but I'm still having trouble understanding what you're after.  Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I have the problem when I using the redirect with new Url.
It is possible, write on url without the redirect.

Comment: Andrew, finally I used the redirect and this I controll with the globla name

Comment: Good to hear you're up.  Thanks for the rep!